# Flutter RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter

The following tree structure is causing a `RenderFlex` error, apparently due to the last `Column > Expanded > Scrollbar > ListView`:

[image: tree structure]

I tried wrapping the `Row` in the last `Column` with `Expanded`, but I still got the same error.

How can I fix this error without explicitly constraining the `ListView` with a fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just wrap the 4th `Row` with `Expanded`:

[image: new layout]

That's the only change I made and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

1. This issue is due to your List view. If you are using
   Listview.builder then please make sure you use shrinkWrap property
   and value of that property is true. Because Listview is not knowing
   how much space is allocated. If this solution is not work then add
   one more propery physics and make it NeverScrollPhysics as well
   remove Scrollbar widget.
2. Otherwise Wrap Listview with Expanded and remove Scrollbar. As well give
   physics to NeverScroll Physics which will also solved your issue.

Above two solution is solve your issue but still you facing the same issue then you need to provide code for that on which line you have issue.

Comment: But I want the list view to be scrollable, and I would like to keep the scrollbar visible. Anyway using `shrinkWrap: true` , `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and removing ScrollBar widget didn't solve the problem (same error)

Comment: I want to add that I remove the `Expanded` from around `Scrollbar`, and add `shrinkWrap: true`, then at first there's no error, but as I keep adding elements to the ListView, I get the error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the bottom"

Comment: Solved it, please see my answer

Comment: Ohh, I understood @AlaaM. Your Row taking unbounded height and width. and Yes, your solution is acceptable